# Trying to add a border to the third row of a table in R of sjPlot using CSS notation

Tags: css, r, sjplot

I am trying to add a border to different rows within an sjPlot::tab_df() table.

Currently my code is this:

```
sjPlot::tab_df(DF, show.footnote =TRUE, alternate.rows=TRUE, CSS = list(css.table = '+font-family: Arial;', css.centeralign = 'text-align: left;', css.firsttablerow = 'font-weight: bold;border-bottom: 1px solid;', css.firsttablecol = 'border-right: 1px solid;', col.header = names(DF))
```

I can manipulate the first and last row using css.firsttablerow and css.lasttablerow, as well as any column I want with css.col3 css.col4 etc. But I cannot figure out how to edit rows manually

I tried css.row3 = 'border-bottom: 1px solid', css.modelcolumn3= ... css.tablerow3 =.... anything I could think of. I'm not very familiar with CSS notation and I tried to look online but couldn't find anything. Please help!

Comment: Don't think that there is an easy option to achieve that. As far as I get it from the docs you can only assign CSS styles based on the class of an element. And inspecting the HTML the table rows are simple `<tr>` tags without any class and hence can't be targeted.